# Relating an entity to two entities or to one relationship between the two entities

Tags: relational-database, entity, relationship, entity-relationship

Suppose I am modeling a many-to-many relationship between a user and a project. That is, a user can be part of multiple projects and a project can have multiple users. This would look something like this:

```
Project
    id: pk
    name: string
User
    id: pk
    name: string
Membership
    id: pk
    project: fk
    user: fk
```

Here, membership reflects the set of users that are part of the project. So anyone who requires access to information related to the project (e.g. tasks) is added to the project through a membership.

Now I want to add a task to this project that can be assigned to a user. When should one relate this task to a user and project individually? And when to the relationship, which is Membership in this example?

These are the three options I can think of:

```
Task1
    id: pk
    name: string
    project: fk -> Project.id
    assigned_to: fk -> User.id

Task2
    id: pk
    name: string
    project: fk -> Project.id
    assigned_to: fk -> Membership.id

Task3
    id: pk
    name: string
    assigned_to: fk -> Membership.id
```

**Task1**:
Similar to Task2 except when the user is no longer a member of the project. In that case the user can still have a task assigned. Also, application level logic must prevent a task from being assigned to a user that is not in the same project as the task.

**Task2**:
Similar to Task1 except when the user is no longer a member of the project. In that case, the reference to membership is lost and a task is left unassigned. Application level logic must prevent a task from being assigned to a membership that is not in the same project as the task.

**Task3**:
When the user is no longer a member of the project, the task is no longer part of a project. A user can assign a task to any membership since it then automatically is part of a project of which the user is a member.

Edit: I added a few options to explain the trade-off I am trying to understand. I would really appreciate it if someone could validate/invalidate the points I raised or add some points to consider.

Comment: Forget about Membership.  Is a Task *done by* or *assigned to* an User ?  Now, is "membership" merely the collection of Users who have assignments in Projects ... or is it different.  If so, please specify.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA I updated the description based on your feedback. Let me know if it now provides the information you requested

Comment: Thanks.  So you have three scenarios and the pros/cons for each.  No.  The point of a database is to record the truth (facts) about the universe.  Sounds like, an User becomes a Member, and a Member can be assigned a Task.  The database is historic, so when a Member is revoked, he can no longer be Assigned to a Task, but his existing facts remain.